# Is it possible to re-render with express after using a request-promise

Tags: node.js, express

I am using `express` and `request-promise`.  I can't get it to re-render after my request-promise.  How would I achieve this?

```
app.get('/v1/mymacro', addon.authenticate(), function (req, res) {
        var rp = require('request-promise');
        var url = "some-url-that-will-redirect";

        res.render('page-1', {
            url: ""
        });

        var r = rp.get(url, function (err, res, body) {            
            url = res.request.uri.href;
            res.render('different-page', {
                url: url
            });                
        })
    }
);
```

Comment: Well, first of all, once you call `res.render`, you've ended the request/response cycle and you wouldn't be able to do another `res.render`. Can you describe the behavior you want to achieve? There is probably a different way to accomplish it.

Comment: I am trying to get the redirected url and pass it to a rendered page.

Comment: If I do not call the first render and wait for the require-promise to return the redirected url, it doesn't render.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do with this: `url = res.request.uri.href;` and why you think that is correct code?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to re-render with express after using a request-promise

No, you cannot call `res.render()` twice for the same request.  Once the first call to `res.render()` is done, the http connection is closed and the response is over.  Calling it a second time will not send anything to the client and will generate a warning from Express.

Also, there is a mistake with your `request-promise` code.  It returns a promise and you should be using that promise, not trying to pass it a callback.  If you want to use callbacks, then just use the `request` library, not `request-promise`.

For request-promise, is should be of the form:

```
rp.get(...).then(...).catch(...);
```

In addition, the line of code:

```
url = res.request.uri.href;
```

does not look correct.  If you explain what you were trying to accomplish with that code, then perhaps we could suggest a solution.

Comment: I was loading an iframe inside my page and it needed the redirect url.

Comment: ah it looks like i had to remove the 1st render and rename the res argument in the get for it to achieve what i was looking for.  thanks for the heads up that calling res.render() closes the http connection.